# How can I divide an array like this?

Tags: php, arrays, divide

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 4 [2] => 2 [3] => 0 [4] => 4 [5] => 1 [6] => 5 [7] => 4 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 2 [11] => 2 [12] => 0 [13] => 5 [14] => 3 )
```

Those is players kill, death and assist numbers. 
Its goes like player 1 kill death assist,
 player 2 kill death assist ...

For example player 1's got 0 kill, died 4 times, and got 2 assists.
Player 2 got 0 kill. died 4 times, and got 1 assists.

Total 5 players.

I want to divide kills, deaths, assists into three different arrays.

Like this:

$kills 0,3,6,9,12:

```
[0] => 0
[1] => 0
[2] => 5
...
```

$deaths 1,4,7,10,13

$assists 2,5,8,11,14

I don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this way:

```
<?php 
$playerStats = array_chunk($yourArray,3); 
?>
```

Now you have every player in a separate array. Then

```
<?php
$kills = $deaths = $assists = array();

foreach($playerStats as $p){
    $kilss[] = $p[0];
    $deaths[] = $p[1];
    $assists[] = $p[2];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working perfectly! Can u tell me what did foreach do to divide it like that?

Comment: foreach has nothing to do with it, array_chunk do the job. That function split an array to new one. In that particular case new array has 3 elements, so it's easy to retrieve any value you need only by index of the element